# How to create folder on google drive error code 17 [resolution was canceled by the user]

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I would like to pass a folder name to my function and create that folder on my signed-in google account

There is my SignInOptions

```
mGoogleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_FULL))
                    .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, mGoogleSignInOptions);
            account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
```

Here is my function.

```
private void createFoler(String folderName) {
        mDriveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(this, account);
        mDriveResourceClient.getRootFolder()
                .continueWithTask(task -> {
                    DriveFolder parentFolder = task.getResult();
                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setTitle(folderName)
                            .setMimeType(DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE)
                            .setStarred(true)
                            .build();
                    return mDriveResourceClient.createFolder(parentFolder, changeSet);
                });
    }
```

The error message:

```
Unable to create file:com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INTERNAL_ERROR: null
```

What configuration do I need to set? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to the scope as I see you are trying Drive_Full
it is stated here on the.

> Note: The Google Drive Android API currently only supports drive.file and drive.appfolder authorization scopes. If your application requires additional permissions or features not yet available in the Drive Android API, you must use the Google APIs Java Client.

You can read more [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth)